# Delphi localization support

Tags: delphi, localization

I am trying to localize a VCL application, but I can't seem to find `LoadNewResourceModule` and `ReinitializeForms`. What unit(s) do I need to add to the `uses` clause for Delphi 10.3.4? Or is there another way to switch language dynamically?

Reference: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Dynamic_Switching_of_Resource_DLLs

Comment: Not an exact answer to your question but an idea: I localize my VCL application using GNU GetText for Delphi (http://dxgettext.po.dk/). This is rather old but it works very well.

Comment: `ReInit.pas` [seems](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/intappsdynamicswitchingofresourcedlls_xml.html) to be included in the Rich Edit sample project in Delphi 2009 at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LoadNewResourceModule and ReinitializeForms are only for an example purposes. They are not very practical because it recreates the form.

Here is a complete [Delphi localization document](https://www.soluling.com/Help/Delphi/Index.htm). It also shows how to make the runtime language switch in the right way.

You can localize your application in many way

- One exe for each language. The application always start in the language of the EXE. Deploy the EXE matching the user's language.
- Original EXE plus one resource DLL for each language. You can have runtime language switch or just select a language at the time when the application starts. Deploy the EXE and any number of resource DLLs.
- One multilingual EXE. Windows will select the language. You have no control for it. Deploy only the multilingual EXE.

Comment: This is a separate tool and not something included in Delphi itself. But it looks promising compared to the localization of Delphi itself (I tried it, but it’s very sensitives to changes as it will produce exceptions and strange texts when not 100% in sync with the main code)...